# How to read data in collection in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, node-modules

I am working on a social media app using Node.js and MongoDB. I've got a problem with reading the data in the collection. I want to get everything from the collection.

Router.js:

```
router.get('/feed', async (req,res) => {
    try{
        await db.client.connect()
        await db.feed(db.client)
        res.render("feed")
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }finally{
        db.client.close()
    }
})
```

Db.js

```
async function feed(client, res){
    let result = await client.db('secret_db').collection('secrets')
    console.log(result)
}
```

Output:

```
Collection {
  s: {
    db: Db { s: [Object] },
    options: {
      raw: false,
      promoteLongs: true,
      promoteValues: true,
      promoteBuffers: false,
      ignoreUndefined: false,
      bsonRegExp: false,
      serializeFunctions: false,
      fieldsAsRaw: {},
      writeConcern: [WriteConcern],
      readPreference: [ReadPreference]
    },
    namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'secret_db', collection: 'secrets' },
    pkFactory: { createPk: [Function: createPk] },
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    },
    bsonOptions: {
      raw: false,
      promoteLongs: true,
      promoteValues: true,
      promoteBuffers: false,
      ignoreUndefined: false,
      bsonRegExp: false,
      serializeFunctions: false,
      fieldsAsRaw: {}
    },
    readConcern: undefined,
    writeConcern: WriteConcern { w: 'majority' },
    slaveOk: false
  }
}
```

Take into consideration that I don't have a problem with rendering the pages. The problem must be done inside the async function feed()

Comment: MongoDB NodeJS Driver documentation has this: [Read Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/) (how to read data from a collection).

Comment: Thank you soo much <3

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find` method of the collection to get the actual data from the DataBase. In your case try this.

```
 let result = await client.db('secret_db').collection('secrets').find({})
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. The guy helped me above and I solved the problem, thank you for your answer.